# MySQL commandline - Do not use autoincrement for zero values

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, terminal

In phpMyAdmin I create an empty MySQL database and then import data (create tables, insert rows) from an .sql file, there is a checkbox "Do not use AUTO_INCREMENT for zero values".

How do I control this "Do not use AUTO_INCREMENT for zero values" option with mysql commandline?

I tried to run in terminal:
mysql -u user_name -p database_name < sql_data_file.sql

That imports the data, but it seems to set the "Do not use AUTO_INCREMENT for zero values" to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhpMyAdmin achives this behaviour by switching on the [`NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero) SQL mode before importing the dump.

Add the below line at the top of your .sql file:

```
SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
```